# powermockito "whenNew" call the answer immediately

Tags: java, powermockito

When I use `PowerMockito`.whenNew...thenAnswer - the answer run immediately!
my code:

```
new Integer(9);
PowerMockito.whenNew(Integer.class).withAnyArguments().thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    System.out.println("kuku int");
    return null;
});
System.out.println("test");
new Integer(10);
```

**output:**

```
kuku int
test
kuku int
```

How to solve this.

Comment: Probably (I'm not sure though), is that PowerMockito, replaces the Integer constructor during compilation, not during runtime, which causes All `new Integer()` calls to go through PowerMockito

Comment: The above code works as expected for me. I hope you have this on top of your Test Class  `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Integer.class})` I got the correct output  : 
test followed by
kuku int